# Is it possible to migrate existing Google and Facebook OAuth users to a new AWS Cognito user pool?

Tags: migration, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I have a user database in a CMS that I'm trying to migrate to a new AWS Cognito user pool.

Some of the users have authentication using OAuth providers (Google and Facebook), the app credentials of which I'm able to add to the user pool as identity providers in Cognito. I'm also able to import the users into Cognito as a CSV file, which results in every user needing a password reset.

What is required to configure the existing Google and Facebook OAuth users so that they use the identity providers in Cognito?

Comment: Have you managed to do that? So far after running a day of testing, it wasn't possible for me.

Comment: No I haven't. I'll probably be looking at this again soon though, so I'll post an update if I find anything useful.